# Is a <link> tag permitted after an </html>?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Seems HTML5 Recommendation has a little ambiguity about `<link>` position: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

There is a phrase

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where metadata content is expected.

And there is no exact definition of this contexts. But the whole page describes a content of this kind e.g. head, title, base, link, meta, style.

There is also a paragraph:

> A link element must have a rel attribute.
>   If the rel attribute is used, the element is restricted to the head  element.

Seems that it has redundant or mutually exclusive phrases.

So could anybody clarify the situation with `<link>` tag position?

Is Google right about https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example or does it violate the W3C Recommendation?

Comment: I don't see how Google's example code ("insert new `link` into the `head`") in any way violates the recommendation...

Comment: Thanks, looks that this is a Russian page bug. On English everything is fine.
On Russian page you can see this text:
`    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          .blue{color:blue;}
        </style>
        </head>
      <body>
        <div class="blue">
          Hello, world!
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css">`

Answer (score 5):

`link` is not permitted outside of the `html` element. The `html` element is the single permitted root element.

Inserting an element into `head` cannot place it out of `html` because `head` must also be in `html`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<link>` element must go inside the `<head>` element, which in turn must go inside the `</html>`.

The only thing you can put outside of an `<html>` is a comment or the DOCTYPE